# Google App Script - Sorry unable to open the file at present

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script which I use to deploy a webapp. However, when i try to run the script by entering the url in mobile, the error shows up "Sorry, unable to open the file at present."

I know that this is an issue with mutiple google accounts on the device. But is there any workaround that is working as on today other than logging out of all accounts. I have gone through similar threads but none of the workarounds are working presently.

I tried opening the same link in incognito and the script runs successfully. Looking for a solution that enables to run the script without going incognito

Comment: Try opening the multiple accounts in different browsers

Comment: Hi @Cooper I am running the script from an android device. Is there something that can be done in Android

Comment: I think maybe just be sure that you have the correct gmail account selected

Comment: I have mutiple accounts in my android device. But there is no way to select an account while running the script through bowser. When i open in BRAVE Browser, it executes fine. Problem is with chrome.

Comment: Hi @Cooper Finally found a working solution myself. adding /a/*/ to the webapp url is solving the issue https://script.google.com/a/*/macros/s/abcdefgh/exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally found a working solution myself. adding /a/*/ to the webapp url is solving the issue

https://script.google.com/a/*/macros/s/abcdefgh/exec

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked but found an easier way to generate it.

I pasted the original link that did not work on a tablet into a browser.

Google then changed it to the one with the specific domain in it and displayed the page.

So its just then a matter of copying the link from the browser address bar.

It then seems to work fine in my tablet when the original link does not.

fyi, the web app script is running as me "The web app will be authorized to run using your account data." and it is set as accessible to Anyone.